# How can I configure sass with webpack/react?

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

I am trying to use sass in webpack+ react, this is my component:

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';

require('style.scss');

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="hello-form"><p>this should be blue</p></div>
        );
    }

}

export default App;
```

This is my config settings:

```
loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ['babel'],
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
            }
        ]
```

When I run webpack I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./App.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../style.scss in C:\Users\d815694\WebstormProjects\reactfrom_scratch
 @ ./App.js 24:0-24
```

How can I configure sass with webpack?

Comment: Can we see all the webpack file.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the scss file is correct? It should be relative to the path your App Component is located.

Comment: @zv.diego it should be require('./style.scss'); it is working now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is like this, after running

```
create-react-app AppName
cd AppName
# RUN THIS
npm install -D concurrently #Allows to run multiple cmd at the time
npm install -D node-sass
```

then in package.json **ADD TO SCRIPTS**

```
"watch": "concurrently --names 'webpack, sass' --prefix name 'npm run start' 'npm run styles:watch'",
"styles:watch": "sass -w src.scss:dest.css"
```

to run it all:

```
npm run watch
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Set your entry to point directly to the style sheet.

E.g.

```
entry: ['./assets/scripts/client.js', './assets/styles/client.css']
```

You don't need to require it from your JS. Bonus is that it makes gulp work if you still use that for something.